# Devise apply css file style to the login form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

i'm using devise for authenticate the users in my rails app, i've exported the views by using the comand

```
rails generate devise:views
```

i see that the files have a 'blank style' so how i can do for apply to them a mine custom file css?

Answer (score 0):

Add gem in your Gemfile

```
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
```

visit link for reference

https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails

http://getbootstrap.com

Answer (score 0):

You can find the generated devise view files in app/views/devise.

Just add needed html elements/css classes the same way you would to other view files.

Keep in mind that this will use your default(application.html.erb) layout.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best way, but it works and it's not too messy:

devise uses the global `application.scss` styles by default.

So I just create a `login.scss`, `signup.scss`, etc. in my route `assets/stylesheets` directory and the add `@import "login.scss"` at the end of `application.scss`.

[image: example stylesheet directory with login page styles in route]

[image: example of importing login styles after global styles]

Just make sure these page are imported after whatever global styles you want to make sure they inherit.

Note:

As my application expands I usually end up abstracting everything into distinct stylesheets so my `application.scss` ends up being a list of imports anyway.

I'm sure there are better ways to do this, but this was the "I'm just a designer and need this to work without overcomplicating things" way,

Answer (score -1):

Installation

Add this line to your application's Gemfile:

gem 'devise-bootstrap-views'
And then execute:

$ bundle
Add some minor css fix to your rails asset pipeline manifest

## SASS

*= require devise_bootstrap_views

## LESS

*= require devise_bootstrap_views_less

rails g devise:views:bootstrap_templates

If you want to go through in detail , you can refer this link : https://github.com/hisea/devise-bootstrap-views